# coldfusion CFM Variables scope

Tags: coldfusion, scope

I have previously asked a question regarding cf scopes on cfm pages (happy that I understand CFC scopes and potential issues), but am still not clear on the variables scope.

In the answers to my previous question, it was suggested that there are no thread safety issues using cfm pages, and you won't get the scenario where two different users access the same page and have race conditions or thread safety probs (even if I just leave my variables in the default cfm variables scope, and that the variables scope for each user will be isolated and independent (here is my last question [Coldfusion Scopes Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679723/coldfusion-scopes-clarification))

However, I have read this blog post http://blog.alexkyprianou.com/2010/09/20/variables-scope-in-coldfusion/ regarding the use of functions on a cfm page and using the variables scope and that seems to suggest a scenario whereby the variables scope is shared between multiple users (I understand this problem in the context of CFCs - them being more akin to java classes and the variables scope being instance variables, so has thread safety issues if the CFC is shared/application scope/singleton) but this seems counter to previous answers - if a variable put in the variables scope by a function on a cfm page can be accessed by other users, then surely variables placed in variables scope directly in cfm page code is the same?

I was hoping for some clear docs and guides but have not really been able to find definitive explanations of the different scopes and where they are available.

Thanks!

Comment: Since the variables scope is not a shared scope there shouldn't be an issue where two users can create a race condition, however it is possible a race condition might happen to a single user.

Comment: Async activity aside, how can there be a race condition? Surely when a user hits a page its is executed in a single threaded, sequential fashion? (I appreciate though that if you don't local scope variables in functions it could get confusing with reusing variables names and not realising things are already initialised). Also, are you saying the blog post is incorrect?

Comment: In the blog post he refers to "request1" and "request2", does he explicitly say those are 2 different users? I didn't get that impression, I was guessing some sort of multi-core concurrency issue.

Comment: Good point - so this still means that a cfm page variables scope is still "wider" than an individual request? So more of a user based scope? Impression I had was that scopes went more like this application > session > request > local - where would the variables scope (cfm pages) fit in? It lasts longer than request scope?

Comment: No, it should be only for the lifecycle of one request, but when you start utilizing things like UDFs which are reuseable chunks of code and you employ variables scope inside of that... it might get dicey. I'll be some CF Gurus can weigh in on this, I only implement UDFs using CFCs with var scoping so it hasn't affected me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dan is correct, and the blog article being referenced in the question is simply wrong. Dan's code demonstrates it, and I have [written-up and tested this thoroughly on my blog](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/overlapping-requests-will-not-cause.html) (it was too big to go here).

The bottom line is the variables scope in a CFM is safe from this sort of race condition because the variables scope for each request is different memory. So one `variables.foo` is not the same as the other `variables.foo`, so neither ever intersect.

The same applies to objects in the variables scope: their internal variables scope is a distinct entity, so any number of requests can instantiate a CFC in the request's variables scope, and the CFC instances' variables scopes are all discrete entities too.

The only time the variables scope can participate in a race condition is the variables scope of an object stored in a shared scope. Because all references to that shared-scope object will be referencing the same object in memory, so the same object's variables scope in memory.

Answer (score 4):

Functions outside of a CFC accessing the variables scope won't have thread safety issues when 2 requests run the code, but if you use cfthread or other parallel features, you could still have problems with the variables scope being changed and this can cause race conditions.   Often this mistake can occur with a variable you use a lot like maybe in a for loop, the "i" variable.

> for(i=1;i<10;i++){t=arr[i]; }

But then another function does this while the first is running:

> for(i=1;i<20;i++){t=arr[i]; }

The "i" variable needs to become a local variable to help make it thread-safe.  You don't want the first loop to be able to go above 10 by mistake and this is hard to debug many times.  I had to fix a ton of "i" variables and others to make my functions thread-safe everywhere when I started caching objects and using cfthread more extensively.

You can also avoid needing to lock by never changing existing objects.  You can instead to the work on copies of them.  This makes the data "immutable".  CFML doesn't have official support for making immutable objects more efficiently, but you can make copies easily.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object

Simple example of thread safe change to an application scope variable:

```
var temp=structnew(); 
// build complete object
temp.myValue=true; 
// set complete object to application scope variable
application.myObject=temp;
```

Writing to any shared object is often dangerous since variables may be undefined or partially constructed.   I always construct the complete object and set it to the shared variable at the end like the example above.  This makes thread-safety easy if it isn't too expensive to re-create the data.   The variables scope in CFC is similar to private member variables in other languages.   If you modify data in shared objects, you'd might to use CFLOCK if you can't make copies instead.

Some of the confusion about coldfusion scopes is related to shared scopes in coldfusion 5 and earlier being less reliable.  They had serious thread safety problems that could cause data corruption or crashes. Two threads were in certain conditions able to write to the same memory at the same time if you didn't lock correctly.  Current CFML engines are able to write to struct keys without the chance of corruption / crashes.  You just can't be sure which data will be actually end up as the value without some consideration of thread-safety now, but it generally won't become corrupted unless you are dealing with non-cfml object types like CFX, Java and others.  A thread-safety mistake could still lead to an infinite loop which could hang the request until it times out, but it shouldn't crash unless it ran out of memory.

Comment: @rhinds - Keep in mind failing to localize function variables can cause problems even within a single thread as [this example](http://daveshuck.com/2006/11/28/thread-safety-example-var-scope-your-loop-index-in-coldfusion-cfcs/) demonstrates. While it uses a cfc, you get the same result if the functions are placed in a .cfm page. Not a race condition per se, but it does illustrate the importance of localizing function variables - always.

Comment: I want to mention that the Railo cfml engine (getrailo.org) has a "local scope mode" option in the admin->scope page which can be set to "always" which will make all unscoped variables local instead of variables scope.  Railo 4.1 will have support for this option on individual functions as well.   This makes converting to thread safe code faster if you intend to migrate to this IMO superior behavior.  Use of variables scope by default is bad code in a function or CFC.

Answer (score 3):

I think the blog is misleading.  However, if you want to see for yourself, write a page with his function.  Make it look something like this.

```
<cffunction name="test" returntype="void">
<cfscript>
foo = now();
sleep(3 * 60 * 1000);  // should be 3 minutes
writedump(foo);
</cfscript>
<cffunction>

<cfdump var="#now()#">
<cfset test()>
```

Run the page.  During the 3 minutes, open another browser or tab and run it again.  Go back to where you first ran it and wait for the results.  If there is no significant difference between the two outputs, then your second page request did not affect your first one.

Note that I have not tried it myself but my bet would be on the 2nd request not affecting the first one.