# Can we append a DateTime to an array with the ArrayAppend() function of ColdFusion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

> ERROR:Can't cast Object type [DateTime] to a value of type [Array]

```
<cfset Seniority=ArrayNew(1)>
  <CFLOOP QUERY="all_employees">
      <cfif isNull(all_employee.TimeInPositionDate) >
          <cfset ArrayAppend(Seniority,all_employee.hiredate)>
      <cfelse>
          <cfset ArrayAppend(Seniority,all_employee.TimeInPositionDate)>
      </cfif>
  </CFLOOP>
```

Comment: can anybody tell me the reaosn ?

Comment: @shawn there???

Comment: To answer the question in the subject line, replace the loop with `<cfset arrayappend(Seniority, now())>`.

Comment: As Dan mentioned, the answer to your question is it possible to append a DateTime object to an array is yes.  So there is something else going on here. You did not provide enough information to help further.

Comment: @miguel-F its the all_employees results from a store procedure. and all_employee.hiredate is column name it should works but the above error is shwoning.

Comment: @DanBracuk its working but it fails when data comes from database column. as mentioned above.

Comment: Show us what the query values are for `all_employee.hiredate` and `all_employee.TimeInPositionDate` in your question. What is their data type in the database?

Comment: @miguel-F datatype is 'datetime' in database and value is '2018-11-06 00:00:00.000' or NULL

Comment: What is the value when the code throws the error?

Comment: "2018-11-06 00:00:00.000" here is the value when code throws error.

Comment: Do you have a date column in `all-employees` called `Seniority`?

Comment: Great question Twillen. @TechleadzTeam you can see that it should work fine - https://www.trycf.com/gist/1605ed50a1f5d7f578eda33ecb8f912d/acf2018?theme=monokai

Comment: You are looping on 'all_employees' and the column you reference comes from 'all_employee'. Should it have the 's' or not?

Comment: You are right the column 'Seniority' presents in database and thats why the error shows thanks a lot sir 
you solve my problem.

Comment: @Twillen you should add an answer so others can see what the actual issue was. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue stems form the [variable lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8815107/923833) in CFML. While you're inside a query loop, ColdFusion will pull from the query scope before your variables scope. Due to there being a column in your query also called `Seniority` your code reads the same as `ArrayAppend(all_employees.Seniority,all_employees.hiredate)`;

Changing the name of your array will solve the issue at hand.

```
 <cfset all_employees = queryNew(
    "Id,TimeInPositionDate,Hiredate,Seniority",
    "Integer,Timestamp,Timestamp,Timestamp",
    [
        {"Id":1,"HireDate":Now(),"Seniority":Now()},
        {"Id":2,"HireDate":Now(),"TimeInPositionDate":Now(),"Seniority":Now()}
    ]
)>

<cfset arrSeniority=ArrayNew(1)>

<CFLOOP QUERY="all_employees">
    <cfif isNull(all_employees.TimeInPositionDate) >
        <cfset ArrayAppend(arrSeniority,all_employees.hiredate)>
    <cfelse>
        <cfset ArrayAppend(arrSeniority,all_employees.TimeInPositionDate)>
    </cfif>
</CFLOOP>
<cfdump var="#arrSeniority#"/>
```

Comment: Yep. Though CF lets you be lazy sometimes, it is a good example of why proper scoping is important.

Answer (score 2):

I still think looping is much easier in CFScript (not to mention the fact that it just *looks* cleaner to me. Anyway, I can knock this down to essentially one line of code (beyond the array creation and looping code).

First, I set up my fake query object:

```
all_employees = QueryNew(
    "id, TimeInPositionDate, hiredate" ,
    "integer, date, date" ,
    [
        {
          id:1 ,
          TimeInPositionDate: "2018-01-01" , 
          hiredate: "2017-01-01"
        } , 
        {
          id:2 ,
          // TimeInPositionDate: Not defined, so NULL
          hiredate: "2017-02-01"

        } , 
        {
          id:3 ,
          TimeInPositionDate: "2018-03-01"
          //hiredate: Not defined, so NULL
         } ,
        {
          id:4 
          //TimeInPositionDate: Not defined, so NULL
          //hiredate: Not defined, so NULL
         } 
    ]
);
```

I have created 3 rows. 1 full row, 1 with just a `TimeInPositionDate`, 1 with just a `hiredate` and 1 with neither. ColdFusion has always been a little odd with how it treats `null`, and it doesn't always mesh up well with a SQL query. In our fake query, we just don't define the rows we want to be `null`.

Next I create my array:

```
Seniority = [] ;
```

We don't have to use `ArrayNew()` to make an array. We can just use implicit notation to be much shorter.

Next we use a `for/in` loop around our query to append row data to our new array.

```
for (r in all_employees) {
    Seniority.append( len(r.TimeInPositionDate) ? r.TimeInPositionDate : r.hiredate ) ;
}
```

Here, we're using the `append()` member function to add to our `Seniority` array. We also use a ternary operation to pick which value we want to add. It basically says that if there is a length to `TimeInPositionDate` for that row, then we use the first condition (`TimeInPositionDate`), otherwise we use `hiredate`.

I though about using an Elvis Operator...

```
Seniority2.append( q.TimeInPositionDate ?: q.hiredate ) ;
```

..., but since the query is likely returning `q.TimeInPositionDate=""` instead of an actual `null` value, then the first value is *technically* defined and gets chosen. That would work on a true `null`, but an empty string isn't a `null`.

You could probably also use `each()` or some other loopish function to iterate through your query object, but I've found `for/in` loops to usually be faster in cases like this. You'll have to test.

You can play with the full thing at:

https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=de107907-234c-4df8-9386-02a288e53313/fdf21791-6cc4-4c55-b923-ad7726efa8ee/b3b6b906-8e3a-4f6b-9ec8-65845efc40f1.cfm

**EDIT**: `NULL`s can be so much fun. If we drop back into some Java, we can get an actual `null` value from the query rather than the `cfquery`-converted empty string, and show that Elvis is still in the building.

```
all_employees.getDate("TimeInPositionDate") ?: all_employees.getDate("hiredate") ) ;
```

Since Java's `getDate()` on a query will get the actual value and can handle a `null`, that correctly chooses the 2nd option for rows where `TimeInPositionDate` is `null`. That said, while I do appreciate the integration of Java and ColdFusion, I do not recommend it in this case. It's doing a lot of mixing of Java into the CF and isn't necessary beyond the demonstration.